# SpringCloud-Bus does not refresh using webhook client

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, monitor, bus, spring-cloud-bus

SpringCloud uses spring-cloud-config-monitor to automatically refresh the configuration of the message bus. It uses the webhook of github. After each update configuration is completed, the result of the request is:
[github webhook response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HW05f.png)，However, the configuration is only updated in config-server, and config-client is not updated, and the config class used is annotated with @RefreshScope. What is the reason?

BeanClass：

```
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "book")
@Component
@RefreshScope
public class BookConfig implements Serializable {

    private Integer max;

    private Integer min;

    private String author;

    private List<String> bookList;
}
```

Comment: I don't know. Can you describe your setup and configuration?